# 2D assets rendering problems

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering

I'm new in 2D programming and right now I'm trying to make a 2D game with some clouds and pipes which are scrolled in the bottom of the screen.

It was easy to deal with the clouds, but I'm having some problems with the pipes- I want to render them like the ones in flappy bird, but horizontally in my case.I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

[Screenshot](http://gyazo.com/e509296e8be3f6488b1acf21291578c2)

```
   public class GameRenderer {

    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    private SpriteBatch batcher;

    private int midPointY;
    private int gameHeight;

    // Game Objects
    private Margarine marg;
    private ScrollHandler scroller;
    private Clouds cloud1, cloud2, cloud3;
    private Pipe pipe1, pipe2, pipe3;

    // Game Assets
    private TextureRegion cloud;
    private TextureRegion pipe;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, int gameHeight, int midPointY) {
        myWorld = world;

        this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
        this.midPointY = midPointY;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, 136, gameHeight);

        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        // Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
        initGameObjects();
        initAssets();
    }

    private void initGameObjects() {
        marg = myWorld.getMargarine();
        scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
        cloud1 = scroller.getCloud1();
        cloud2 = scroller.getCloud2();
        cloud3 = scroller.getCloud3();
         pipe1 = scroller.getPipe1();
         pipe2 = scroller.getPipe2();
         pipe3 = scroller.getPipe3();  

    }

    private void initAssets() {

        cloud = AssetLoader.cloud;
        pipe = AssetLoader.pipe;
    }

    public void render(float runTime) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(102 / 255.0f, 102 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);


        shapeRenderer.end();

        batcher.begin();

        //clouds

        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud1.getX(), cloud1.getY(), cloud1.getWidth(),
                cloud1.getHeight());

        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud2.getX(), cloud2.getY(), cloud2.getWidth(),
                cloud2.getHeight());

        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud3.getX(), cloud3.getY(), cloud3.getWidth(),
                cloud3.getHeight());

        //pipes

        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe1.getX(), pipe1.getY(), pipe1.getWidth(),
                pipe1.getHeight());
        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe1.getX(), pipe1.getY() + pipe1.getHeight() + 45,
                pipe1.getWidth(), midPointY + 66 - (pipe1.getHeight() + 45));

        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe2.getX(), pipe2.getY(), pipe2.getWidth(),
                pipe2.getHeight());
        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe2.getX(), pipe2.getY() + pipe2.getHeight() + 45,
                pipe2.getWidth(), midPointY + 66 - (pipe2.getHeight() + 45));

        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe3.getX(), pipe3.getY(), pipe3.getWidth(),
                pipe3.getHeight());
        batcher.draw(pipe, pipe3.getX(), pipe3.getY() + pipe3.getHeight() + 45,
                pipe3.getWidth(), midPointY + 66 - (pipe3.getHeight() + 45));


        //margarine
        batcher.draw(AssetLoader.marg, marg.getX(), marg.getY(),
                marg.getWidth(), marg.getHeight());



        batcher.end();

    }

}


public class Pipe extends Scrollable {

    private Random r;

    // When Pipe's constructor is invoked, invoke the super (Scrollable)
    // constructor
    public Pipe(float x, float y, int width, int height, float scrollSpeed) {
        super(x, y, width, height, scrollSpeed);
        // Initialize a Random object for Random number generation
        r = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(float newX) {
        // Call the reset method in the superclass (Scrollable)
        super.reset(newX);
        // Change the height to a random number
        height = r.nextInt(90) + 15;
    }
}

 public ScrollHandler(float yPos) {

        cloud1= new Clouds(80, 0, 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);
        cloud2 = new Clouds(50 , cloud1.getTailY(), 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);
        cloud3 = new Clouds(10, cloud2.getTailY(), 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);

        pipe1 = new Pipe(210, 0, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED);
        pipe2 = new Pipe(0, pipe1.getTailY() + PIPE_GAP, 22, 70, SCROLL_SPEED);
        pipe3 = new Pipe(0, pipe1.getTailY() + PIPE_GAP, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // Update our objects

        cloud1.update(delta);
        cloud2.update(delta);
        cloud3.update(delta);

        pipe1.update(delta);
        pipe2.update(delta);
        pipe3.update(delta);


         if (cloud1.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud1.reset(cloud3.getTailY());

         } else if (cloud2.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud2.reset(cloud1.getTailY());

         } else if (cloud3.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud3.reset(cloud2.getTailY());
         }


         if (pipe1.isScrolledDown()) {
             pipe1.reset(pipe3.getTailY() + PIPE_GAP);
         } else if (pipe2.isScrolledDown()) {
             pipe2.reset(pipe1.getTailY() + PIPE_GAP);

         } else if (pipe3.isScrolledDown()) {
             pipe3.reset(pipe2.getTailY() + PIPE_GAP);
         }

}

    public Clouds getCloud1() {
        return cloud1;
    }

    public Clouds getCloud2() {
        return cloud2;
    }

    public Clouds getCloud3() {
        return cloud3;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe1() {
        return pipe1;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe2() {
        return pipe2;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe3() {
        return pipe3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. By mistake I switched the height and the width.